# Display results of a google image search

Tags: html, google-api

I want to know if it's possible to display the first n images of a google image search (with a pre-defined search keyword) on my page.

For instance, I have this link
https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=red+apple

I want to display the first 5 result on my website on page load.

I would like to solve this without a server, on client side when the visitor visits the page.

Is this possible?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm looking for something similar.